# Can we write separate code for only iOS in Ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I need a code to run for only iOS in my hybrid app made from Ionic framework. How can I do this?

We use hybrid apps which work on iOS, Android, Windows and Blackberry. I need to implement such a condition in which a part of my code only works for iOS and not for Android or any other platform.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

ionic offer platform api

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/

and example is

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
      // This will only print when on iOS
//your code here
      console.log('I am an iOS device!');
    }
  }
}
```